# Enquire.js and AngularJS integration

Tags: angularjs, enquire.js

What would be best practice on how to use Enquire.js together with AngularJS? I googled and couldn't find any good documentation about it.

Comment: https://github.com/Bitponics/angular-enquire-breakpoints

Comment: Yes I've seen that but the docs are not very informative. Do you have any experience with it?

Comment: I have not used it, but it seems straightforward. It is basically a directive you add to your view. You can set breakpoints that fire events when the view is resized - you can set the breakpoints to match your media query values.